# Sharepoint 2013 Topology Broke Down

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, topology, troubleshooting

Almost three years ago i installed Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise for test purposes and i didn't planned very well the topology so i prepared one server as a web server and used TFS database server as database server. Everything had worked well and we started to use it instead of just testing.

One month ago our windows administrators created another Active Directory domain and moved our clients and users. But all other systems like TFS and Sharepoint were left at legacy domain. Both of the systems were working like a charm, only we had to use our legacy domain accounts to login them.

Two days ago i decided to move TFS from legacy domain to new domain, i followed the instructions and moved. But i forgot that Sharepoint was using same database server. Due to SQL Server login problems Sharepoint stopped working. Now i have been strugling with Sharepoint to bring back it life.

I tried to update connection string manually via registry or stsadm but it didn't worked. Then, I moved Sharepoint web server to new domain too and changed the service accounts and application pool accounts according to the new domain but it didn't helped me.Also I changed SQL Server logins and rights according to the new domain in database server.

Now i cannot find a way to recover Sharepoint. There are lots of data and files in databases so it is very important for me. I am not sure that if i install a new instance of Sharepoint 2013 and attach old conent databases with configuration database.

I hope you can guide me to solve my problem.

PS: Full system backups of TFS and Sharepoint before moving new domain are existing.So I planned to restore backups to new servers and try to backup data in Sharepoint, if i cannot find a way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the train and now the only option is rebuild the farm on new domain.For rebuilding you have to two options.

**Options 1** as you TFS DB server still have all the content DBs..

- build a new farm on new domain
- Create & configure all the web application & service applications
- Now attach the old content DB to right web app.
- Now you have to run the migrate user against each user, because all the ids belong to old domain. **But** if you have trust between old and new domain then ids will work.

**Option #2**

- Build new farm on new domain.
- restore the farm backup you had before the moving the server.

.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Actually i was afraiding of missing the train ;) If options #2 will restore all the configuration i may choose that way. But  i wonder that, restoring the backups from legacy domain to the new farm on new domain will work? And if i choose option #1 isn't there any way to recover configuration?

Comment: with option 1 you cant recover the configuration, you have to manully apply the Customization, Updating AAM, Running full crawl on search etc...with 2nd option, you need to apply less effort...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428314.aspx i recommend you dont do any thing on existing share point serves, Spin a farm on new server and perform a  test restore and then analyze the result.

Comment: I 2nd this - Even small things like renaming a SharePoint server can seem to work at first, but have issues appear weeks or months later.  I personally would go with route #1 and just create a new farm and configuration, make sure that works, then bring in the content. You can use something like AutoSPinstaller to help ease the pain of re-installation.

Comment: I got it, i was looking for a way to fix current topology but as i understood there is no way to achieve this. So we are preparing a new farm topology for new instance. After that i need to find a way to attach old content dbs to new instance. @WaqasSarwarMCSE the link you sent me is about restoring backups if i am not wrong, right?